# Permission Issue when creating an ECS Service with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, elastic-container-registry

I am trying to create an ECS service in a cloud formation json.

Here is the role I created ( I am using one role for multiple things at the moment and will break them up later).

```
"LambdaBrownlowRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": "LambdaBrownlowRole",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                  "events.amazonaws.com",
                  "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com",
                  "ecs.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "LambdaBrownlowPolicy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "s3:GetObject",
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:ListBucket",
                    "s3:DeleteObject"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::afl-game-data/*",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::afl-game-data"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "dynamodb:PutItem",
                    "dynamodb:GetItem",
                    "dynamodb:Query",
                    "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                    "dynamodb:Scan",
                    "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                    "dynamodb:BatchGetItem"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents",
                    "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                    "ecs:CreateService",
                    "ecs:DescribeServices",
                    "ecs:UpdateService"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "*"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Here is the json snippet for the resources in question.

```
 "ECSBrownlowTaskDefinition": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
      "Properties": {
        "Family": "afl-brownlow-scrape",
        "ExecutionRoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaBrownlowRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Memory": "512",
        "Cpu": "256",
        "TaskRoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaBrownlowRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "RequiresCompatibilities": [
          "FARGATE"
        ],
        "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
        "ContainerDefinitions": [
          {
            "Name": "BrownlowScrape",
            "Image": {
              "Ref": "ECRRepositoryUriParameter"
            },
            "Essential": true,
            "Environment": [
              {
                "Name": "YEAR_TO_QUERY",
                "Value": {
                  "Ref": "YearToQueryParameter"
                }
              },
              {
                "Name": "BUCKET_NAME",
                "Value": {
                  "Ref": "BucketNameParameter"
                }
              },
              {
                "Name": "DATA_PATH",
                "Value": {
                  "Ref": "DataPathParameter"
                }
              }
            ],
            "LogConfiguration": {
              "LogDriver": "awslogs",
              "Options": {
                "awslogs-group": {
                  "Ref": "AFLScrapeLogGroup"
                },
                "awslogs-region": {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "AFLScrapeLogGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "LogGroupName": "/ecs/afl-brownlow-scrape"
      }
    },
    "ECSServiceScrapeAFL": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
      "Properties": {
        "Cluster": "afl-brownlow-cluster",
        "ServiceName": "ServiceECSBrownlow",
        "TaskDefinition": {
          "Ref": "ECSBrownlowTaskDefinition"
        },
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "DesiredCount": 0,
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaBrownlowRole", "Arn"]
        }
      }
    },
    "ECSScrapeScheduledRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "ecs-brownlow-scrape-weekly",
        "Description": "Scheduled rule for ECS brownlow-scrape",
        "RoleArn": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaExecutionRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "ScheduleExpression": "cron(0/10 * ? * * *)",
        "State": "ENABLED",
        "Targets": [
          {
            "Arn": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "ECSServiceScrapeAFL",
                "Arn"
              ]
            },
            "Id": "ecs-brownlow-scrape",
            "EcsParameters": {
              "TaskDefinitionArn": {
                "Ref": "ECSBrownlowTaskDefinition"
              },
              "TaskCount": 1,
              "LaunchType": "FARGATE"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

On the creation of ECSServiceScrapeAFL, I get the following error:

Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: CreateService error: Access denied (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: XXX; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: XXX, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Go to CloudTrail event history and filter to see CreateService events.  Find the one that corresponds to your timing and examine the details to see what it shows as the principal making the request.  That can help you see where permissions are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think what might be going on is that since you've set both the task and execution roles as your LambdaBrownlowRole you need to create a trust policy for this role that allows the ecs principle to assume this role. You will also need to allow ecs permission to pull images from the ecr repo you've created for this service.